# doubt with a multiple choice question

Tags: homework, ecology, population-dynamics, population-biology

Permanent decrease in population would occur due to-

A) Migration B) Natality C) Emigration D) Mortality E) Territoriality .

It's obvious that C) & D) options are possible . But I'm confused about which one is more correct and what is the cause ?

The answer is given : C

Comment: please see [this post](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/minimum-effort-on-homework-questions-multiple-choice-questions) and [this post](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/this-is-the-title-of-the-meta-post-i-just-wrote)

Comment: Emigration is a permanent phenomenon. Mortality, on the other hand, is dependant on various factors such as epidemics, health, life expectancy, etc. A change in these factors leads to a consequent change in the mortality rate. For instance, if an epidemic plaguing a country is eradicated, then the rate of decrease in population would slow down. Hence, it can lead to an increase in population as compared to the population during the epidemic.

Comment: Aside the fac that the post is off-topic, It is definitely a poorly phrased question. Is it really the way the exact way the question was phrased? There was not even the term "size" after "population"? Both C and D sounds equally correct.

Comment: @ Remi.b : The question was on my MCQ book & i didn't commit any changes as i had doubt with the answer . If you have problem , Do an edit or don't give advices

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is just me, but I'd consider this a pretty badly worded question. For models of population dynamics, the rate at which the size of a population changes over time is normally accepted to be the net balance of four fundamental processes: **Birth**, **Immigration**, **Death**, and **Emigration** ('**BIDE**'; see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_population_models)). Birth and immigration increase a population, death and emigration decrease it. Unless you exterminate a species then it's going to be pretty difficult to assert that a population decrease from either source is 'permanent' - new individuals are likely to be born into the local population and/or immigrate eventually.

An example that specifically refutes the assertion that 'emigration results in a permanent decline in population size' would be a [**source-sink metapopulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source%E2%80%93sink_dynamics), in which emigration repeatedly/constantly occurs from the 'source' population but it doesn't permanently decrease in size.

As a lesser quibble, although 'migration' can be taken to refer to temporary movement/resettling, it is pretty common to consider immigration and emigration to each be components of migration.

So I would certainly argue that for the question **as asked**, 'D' is at least as valid an answer as 'C', but in both cases it is impossible to say a *permanent* decrease would occur. At the same time, if it was changed to 'could occur', you could make a case that 'A' could be a valid answer (since 'migration' includes emigration).

Answer (score 0):

A and C is more obvious answers.

Mortality and natality are two sides of the same coin there is a balance between them and are dependent on several factors.
Migration is temporary (Wiki: An instance of moving to live in another place for a while), whereas emigration is to permanently move and populate that area.

Comment: Through Migration , i tried to mean Immigration

Comment: anyways, I feel the question is incomplete.